# Redirect Non WWW to WWW format and to HTTPS in VirtualHost

Tags: apache, virtualhost, http-redirect, amazon-elb, apache2.2

A **non-www redirect to www and forcing https**, returns **[302 temporary redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302)**  on only `http://www.example.com`.

See [Status Codes](http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php) below per protocol and hostname - test my site http://www.mypetcerts.com

- https://www.example.com -> 200
- https://example.com -> 301 - https://www.example.com
- http://example.com -> 301 -> https://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com -> 302 -> https://www.example.com

**example.conf**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.example.com
       # server config 
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) https://www.mypetcerts.com/$1
    </VirtualHost>
```

I imagine this is because I am hitting VirtualHost 1 above without an https redirect because the canonical name was correct and there was no need to hit the VirtualHost 2 at ServerName example.com. Anyone have an answer with this style set up? I am running on Amazon ELB as well.

*Note: This is Apache2.2 I can't take advantage of Apache2.4 IF directives :(*

I suppose doing a redirect to www then to https is possible, but from my understanding performing a multiple redirect (e.g. to www first then to https) is not the great for SEO.

I need all possible outcomes to goto https://www.example.com with a single [301 permanent redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301).

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Using a combination of **Redirect** and **Rewrite** I am able to get the single 301 permanent redirect from HTTP, non www to HTTPS www. I am using the RewriteCond described shown below to deal with my backend listener only on HTTP (e.g. :80).

See here: [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
   # additional optional server config 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `X-Forwarded-Proto` is not necessarily gonna be set for all HTTPS requests.

Comment: Will you please expand on your response, or edit the answer provided with more information to help provide a more complete solution with possible variants?

Comment: An HTTPS request will **not always** have a `X-Forwarded-Proto` header set. Meaning that using the above config, it is possible that a HTTPS request will **not** be redirected correctly as the question asks.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Would  you like to update my answer with an alternative or enhanced solution?